# Getting a "Subscript out of range" error for a simple Range.Copy line. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: excel, vba

My code looks like this:

```
Sub Copy_all_OpenSO()

Workbooks("SAP Open Sales Orders with SWB Details.xlsx").Worksheets("SAP Open Sales Orders with SWB").Range("A2:CH10000").Copy _
Destination:=Workbooks("SAP Open Sales Orders with SWB.xlsm").Worksheets("SAP Open Sales Orders with SWB").Range("A2")

End Sub
```

I read a few answers on similar errors, but still unable to sort this one out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Either one of the workbook name is incorrect or the worksheet name is incorrect

Comment: Create individual objects for workbook and worksheet. This way you will be able to narrow down which is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SiddharthRout! I tried this, and the code is giving em the error while defining the source sheet. This error persists even when I changed the Sheet name in the code and the file to "Sheet1".

Comment: Workbooks("SAP Open Sales Orders with SWB Details.xlsx") is ***Open***, right?

Comment: Yes, both the workbooks are open.